# Inheritance - Why do superclasses inherit subclass instances?

Tags: java, inheritance

Assume five classes were created like this:

[image]

and they were all connected through inheritance as shown, and newFruit is an instance of GoldenDelicious and myOrange is an instance of Orange.

Here are my questions:

1. Why would newFruit be an instance of Apple and Fruit but not Macintosh?
2. Why would myOrange be an instance of Fruit and not Apple?

With my understanding of inheritance, all subclasses of Apple (GoldenDelicious and Macintosh) would have its instances but the superclass of Apple (Fruit) would not. Why is this not the case?

Comment: You're looking at the tree upside-down. Seriously. Try drawing it with "fruit" at the bottom and see if it makes more sense to you.

Comment: 1. The same reason I (newFruit) am an instance of Human (GoldenDelicious) and Primate (Apple), but not Chimpanzee (Macintosh).

2. Because a Bird (Orange) and a Primate (Apple) are both Animals (Fruits) but a Bird is not a Primate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Not considering interfaces to keep it simple; talking only of classes inheritance)*

If you have an inheritance tree like in the picture, 
then an instance of a class would also be an instance of all parent nodes, but not siblings.

Because inheritance in Java is an [**"is a"** relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a).

In the real world, if `newFruit` is a `GoldenDelicious`, then **it's an** `Apple` and also **it's a** `Fruit`. But a `GoldenDelicious` object **is not** and `Orange`. This seems intuitive.

Comment: I was taught that all subclasses have everything including instances (that are public) from the superclass and maybe more. Since _newFruit_ was created in _GoldenDelicious_, all potential subclasses of _GoldenDelicious_ have _newFruit_, that's understandable. What I want to know now is why something created in the subclass passes back to the superclass, I understand the "is a" relationship, a _GoldenDelicious_ "is an" _Apple_, but how does that equate to passing instances back to _Apple_ from _GoldenDelicious_?

Comment: `newFruit` *is an instance of* `GoldenDelicious`, which in turn *is an* `Apple`, which in turn *is a* `Fruit`. Thus, `newFruit` has all properties and methods (let's call it _"behavior"_) defined by `GoldenDelicious`. `GoldenDelicious` may define its own behavior, and also inherits the behavior of `Apple` and (transitively) the behavior of `Fruit`. Summarizing, `newFruit` has all properties and methods defined in `GoldenDelicious`, `Apple` and `Fruit`.

Comment: However, if you _assign_ an instance of `GoldenDelicious` to a variable of type `Apple`, i.e. `Apple apple = new GoldenDelicious();` then it will _still_ be an instance of `GoldenDelicious` with all its additional properties/methods (compared to `Apple`). But you would **not** be able to **access** these additional properties/methods by this variable. You would need to to [downcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) to do this: `((GoldenDelicious) apple).methodOfGolderDelicious()`.